# Deleting an object from an vector

Tags: c++, vector

I've got a problem : I have a vector `vector<TSquare> SquaresList;` and when I try to delete an member of it (which is a TSquare instance)`delete SquaresList[l];` it says this: `main.cpp|499|error: type ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<TSquare> >::value_type {aka class TSquare}’ argument given to ‘delete’, expected pointer|`,and i don't understand why.

I saw some similar questions but i didn't quite understand it...

Comment: delete SquaresList[SquaresList.begin() +  l];

Comment: @peakpeak - Seriously? Are you *trying* to make the OP's code crash?